# Chrome Extension: Message response not sent in "production"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have been trying for hours, but I could not make it work. This is happening only on a published chrome extension not on my unpacked build

this is the pop-up script:

```js
_handleMessageResponse = (response) => {
    console.log(response) // undefined
  };

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  "message",
  this._handleMessageResponse
);
```

and on my background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  async (
    message,
    _sender: any,
    sendResponse: any
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await someAsyncApiCall();
      console.log(response) // {some: 'prop'}
      sendResponse({
        response
      });
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      sendResponse({ errorMessage: e.message });
      return true;
    }
  }
);
```

**In my local environment it returns an object, while in a published extension returns undefined**.
In the published extension the response in the background script is of course defined.

Probably is because is an async function, but I did not find anything rather then returning true from the handler, but even that (like in my code is showing) it did not working.

Comment: A typical cause is to put the onMessage listener inside onInstalled, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472453).

Comment: Also, you can't use an `async` function directly as a listener for onMessage **and** `return true` in Chrome, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024910).

Comment: yea, I have figured out, thanks. And that is why it was working in my local (still weird)