# Keyboard shortcuts not working on published extension, but working when loading unpacked developer extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created keyboard shortcuts in my extension that worked while I was testing, but don't work when I install my published version. They are:

Default: Ctrl+Shift+A, Ctrl+Shift+S
Mac: MacCtrl + D, MacCtrl + S

Are these overriding something that they shouldn't be? Based on the documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/) these keyboard shortcuts should work.

Comment: Sounds like [How to aim a bug in Chromium browser extension that there won't be if installed locally in Dev mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472453)

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks for the response! I already had the listeners instantiated outside of the chrome.runtime.onInstalled. I took a peek at chrome://extensions/shortcuts, and one of the keyboard shortcuts wasn't populated (even though it was specified in the manifest), and the other didn't work. Removing, then adding them again worked, so I have a temporary fix and will keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I uninstalled and reinstalled the extension, and then the keyboard shortcuts began to work. If anyone else is having this problem and they just recently published their extension, wait a few days and that may solve the problem.