# I cant seem to figure out what permissions I may be missing for my chrome extension. It works in developer mode but not on the chrome store

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Running into a bit of an issue here after my extension has been published on the chrome store. The extension simply "busts" browser cache by appending a query param at the end of any url. It works fine if I upload the package directly to chrome locally for development but when the file is published on the chrome store (approved and all) it doesnt seem to work at all.

I am thinking that I might be missing some kind of permissions in the manifest but I am not certain.

The way that this is supposed to work is that you simply click on the extension icon and the background script fires off modifying the URL and reloading the page.

Thoughts would be much appreciated!

**manifest.json**

```
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "version": "1.0.1",
   "name": "Cache Buster",
   "description": "Allows a user to bust their cache without needing to type in the URL",
   "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
   ],
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
         "16": "images/get_started16.png",
         "32": "images/get_started32.png",
         "48": "images/get_started48.png",
         "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      }
   },
   "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
   }
}
```

**background script**

```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow:true}, tabs => {
         let url= tabs[0].url;
         let busterDigits = [];
         function findDigits() {
            for (i =0; i < 4; i++) {
               let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
               busterDigits.push(n);
            }
         }
         function checkParam() {
           if ( url.includes("?") && !url.includes('beejBuster')) {
               url = url + "&beejBuster=" + busterDigits.join("").toString();
            } else if (url.includes("?") && url.includes('beejBuster')) {
               url = url.split('beejBuster=')
               url.pop()
               url = url + 'beejBuster=' + busterDigits.join('').toString();
            } else {
               url = url + "?beejBuster=" + busterDigits.join("").toString();
            }
         }
         findDigits();
         checkParam();
         console.log(url);

         chrome.tabs.update({url: url})
         
      })
   }); 
 });
```

Comment: The posted code seems unrelated. What else is in background.js? If you use onInstalled then it's probably [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472453).

Comment: @wOxxOm This is the entire background script. But I think you nailed it with that link you sent -- appreciate it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I actually omitted the first line on accident. It was the onInstalled. Appreciate your help.