# google extension - extension does not work after publishing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i have strange problem. When I load my exntesion directly from package everything works but when I add it to chrome from google web store its not working. No errors, no anything.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: The question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve). Sounds like [onInstalled problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57472112)

Comment: so setting up persistent to true should resolve the issue?

Comment: It's a bad solution but yes it will.

Comment: ...assuming the problem is the same.

Comment: It didn't help. After publication still not working. Can I test somehow before publishing if its gonna work?

Comment: The question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: I figured out that extension has different ID while in DEV mode. Maybe thats the reason. Ill update and let you know.

Comment: If you don't use the id anywhere explicitly then it doesn't matter.