# Google Chrome extension MV3 chrome.contextMenus onClicked event listener

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am wondering if anyone updated their codebase from V2 to V3 and how are they handling this considering background is not persistent anymore. I have some event listeners on clicked however because the service worker goes inactive after a short period of time this events are not getting triggered for me.
Would love to hear some tips about handling this scenario.
-Edit-

Please see below the code

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "log-selection",
    "title": "Do Something",
    "contexts": ["selection"],
  });
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(clickEventInfo);
});

function clickEventInfo(info, tab) {

    if(info.menuItemId == "log-selection")
    {
        var dataInfo = {
            name: info.selectionText
        }

        chrome.storage.local.set({dataInfo});
        chrome.tabs.create({url:"section/some_page.html"});
    }
}
```

So why is this working when the service worker is active however not doing anything when it goes inactive?

Comment: @wOxxOm Hey, I have updated my post with more information, any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: Move the line with onClicked outside of onInstalled. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472453) for an explanation.