# Contextmenu onClicked listener fires multiple times on Chrome extension MV3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am migrating a chrome extension to MV3. The extension allows to reverse search images on Google Images. The extension has a popup page. Here is the `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "desc",
  "short_name": "short_name",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "title",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon-16.png",
    "48": "img/icon-48.png",
    "128": "img/icon-128.png"
  }
}
```

In my `background.js` file, I have the following code to create the contextMenu and add the onClicked listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: id,
    title: "Google Reverse Search",
    contexts: ["image"],
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: myUrl
    });
);
```

Now, this code works and the reverse search opens a new Google Images tab. However, if I have one  popup extension page opened in Chrome, two new Google Image tabs are created when I click on the contextMenu item. More generally, every tab (instance) will create a new Google Image tab when I click on the contextMenu item.

Is it possible to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Try to move `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(..)` in the callback of the `onInstalled` event. I think the problem is that you're adding a new click listener every time the service worker is started.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but after 30 seconds the service worker becomes inactive and it doesn't work anymore

Comment: It should not matter if the service stops, if you register event listeners, when those events occur, the service will be started

Comment: @Sala I had this exact problem - it was happening unpredictably for me, and I could not figure out why it was happening. I think this might be a bug in Chrome, because it was not happening for the MV2 version of the extension. I'm pretty sure it was not caused by my own misunderstanding of how the service worker script may be invoked multiple times

Comment: @Titus I observed the same behavior as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610783/google-chrome-extension-mv3-chrome-contextmenus-onclicked-event-listener which is why I moved it outside of `onInstalled`

Comment: You probably included background.js in your popup.html by mistake. Otherwise, it'd be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm My `background.js` is not included in the `popup.html` so yeah probably a bug

Comment: @Sala - Call `chrome.contextMenus.removeAll()` before calling `chrome.contextMenus.create()`. In other words, put `chrome.contextMenus.create()` in the callback of `chrome.contextMenus.removeAll()`. Let us know if this fixes the problem.

Comment: @ThomasMueller when I had this problem, that was exactly what I was doing. It didn't help.