# Why does my Chrome extension timer not update in real-time after publishing to the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, timer, alarm, chrome-web-store

I've developed a Chrome extension with a timer feature. When I load the extension unpacked directly from the Chrome Extensions page, it works flawlessly, updating in real-time. However, after packaging and publishing it to the Chrome Web Store, the timer doesn't seem to update in real-time anymore, even though the code is identical.

Details:

The extension uses Chrome's alarms API to update every second.
It communicates between the background script and a popup to display the timer.
There's no console error or warning when this issue occurs.
The only noticeable difference between the local and store version is a _metadata folder in the store version, containing computed_hashes.json and verified_contents.json.

What I tried:

- Verified that the local and store version files are the same.
- Tested with a new browser profile and on another Chromium browser (Edge) - the issue persists.
- Used the unpacked version of the extension, and it works as expected.

Expected Behavior:
The timer should update every second, reflecting the real-time countdown, regardless of whether it's loaded from the store or locally.

Comment: You either didn't use any `chrome` event listeners or you incorrectly put them inside onInstalled, see [Published extension doesn't work with chrome API listeners inside onInstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57472112), or maybe inside another asynchronous code, which is also a mistake.

Comment: "The extension uses Chrome's alarms API to update every second"

The minimun time alarms interval in production is 1 minute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.